# How to move a unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers, move-semantics, unique-ptr

I have this code:

```
unique_ptr<int[]> p1; //this is now 2 lines
unique_ptr<int[]> fitness_data (new int[9]);

...add data to fitness_data...

p1 = std::move(fitness_data); //Attempt 1 or...
p1(std::move(fitness_data)); //Attempt 2. Either attempt is commented. 
p1.unique_ptr((std::move(fitness_data))); //Attempt 3
```

Attempt 1 stops the program with exit code 139. My IDE, CLion gives the error

> 'unique_ptr::operator=(const unique_ptr &)' is deleted

Attempt 2 does not compile with error:

> error: no match for call to ‘(std::unique_ptr) (std::remove_reference&>::type)’
>            p1(std::move(fitness_data));

Attempt 3 does not compile with error:

> error: invalid use of ‘std::unique_ptr::unique_ptr’
>            p1.unique_ptr((std::move(fitness_data)));

I'm assuming that the error is referring to an attempt made to copy the pointer, But I need to move it.

For my example, p1 is declared in the same scope as fitness_data. However, I would like it to be part of a separate data structure, like "structure->p1"

I would appreciate any help. I would hate to have to move back to manually freeing memory again. Unfortunately, the version of OpenMP we are allowed to use does not get along with vectors.

Thanks, Daniel

Comment: Please post more code, the line where you declare `p1` is ambiguous depending on context (are you using the comma as an operator? Is this a class initializer?). What is the type of `fitness_data`?

Comment: @Dai, It's multiple declarations in a single line. Both are `unique_ptr<int[]>`.

Comment: Attempt 1 [compiles](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0853a3cb7542a669) in my reproduction attempt. Attempt 2 is trying to use the function call operator, not reassign it. I wouldn't be completely surprised if it's just an IDE issue. CLion is still pretty new and I heard it got a big parsing overhaul in 1.1.

Comment: Compiles ok for me: https://ideone.com/jfsOyj

Comment: Have you tried using `std::unique_ptr::swap`?

Comment: I've added another attempt. Attempt 1 compiles fine for me too, but the program exits after executing that line.

Comment: The IDE error is just a CLion error, and the segfault was my own stupid fault.

Thanks guys.

Comment: If your IDE makes trouble there are 2 workarounds:

'std::swap(p1, fitness_data);
fitness_data.release();
'

or 

'p1.reset(fitness_data.release());'

But the first attempt should work...

Comment: p1 = fitness_data;